# RSA_private_decrypt() failing randomly: block type is not 02

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am using openssl 0.9.6g with C++. I have generated RSA public/private keypair. I have [openssl.net](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/) framework which is based on 1.0.0d version of openssl. I am encrypting text using public key with openssl.net and when I try to decrypt in my C++ code, I am getting random failure. Sometimes I am able to retrieve the data but some other times I am getting following error:

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02
```

I am not sure what exactly is happening. If I use the encrypted data and the private key in openssl.net (which originally encrypted the data), I am able to decrypt.

My C++ code is:

```
const char *p="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIICXgIBAAKBgQDOx0DsbBURESmUVivbiHXqJdaJw8j3v27RC5ArUKIFbzgoqge+\n\
ZA9IcWA+WDjW4auzrzhK3sQTHRbkYCkSZsHdkHFu1viYDtK0Y1PUzm45xGAjOD2R\n\
TbYTMDyUAwDwERoIamPFLa/kQ/4AQnL6F2C6NQPtnkCITLsB0+pbQLvLzwIDAQAB\n\
AoGBAJ7aDfNSuQBqieHOLVUyyTs/JEijowFJDG4GDxRnloDMR31d2iMWpXMGvmRG\n\
zCuwJIMeqgVCi6kPYOXDRepADM+zPo3Qh6hSS5AhzgY27xitjOqZVrJX7J/Y1N+i\n\
Fd+GPvj7FuOvQTQw9MVkEDQYvTaC3hXVOS5akzqwes5gAL45AkEA6OMl4+ROmDhV\n\
bBwif4sy4Em1MhJMU8RpWzk6f/ETp7gwejdgnU4oHOLz8d7j5rhBnC1mXlUnsaOA\n\
3rYimRqDdQJBAONMxKUXtbEOtP34IecM4uC0COXmYiTo9FdUoaoLOxVTBTo2antb\n\
aEZHvGJJFhvn4ucWtDju15rGCkwhNImDPbMCQQDLNjm/y14RUUaomTw5EtuH/okP\n\
cgwMJBzSrvMu5MuD1CLo4h155dL2scqvSRCQKEOH5c2njqKeTM+Mhl1WP15pAkEA\n\
0lYp6rREGDKJ3jMN/Gd6U4GGcmh9Dbbc1Sul5ls6M4N95N6SLtDpb4/WjgUgBnbR\n\
DBOAdubecYUt5kEcAtyF7QJAYU0OICV21B6t8lsoULHTYDOMm5P7PuMN6w3F+h0Z\n\
sdyMfD6pBKBw/bBNwApBaypIKK9leLdbebor23reKBi+9w==\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
strKey = p;
BIO *pBPK = NULL;
RSA *pPrivKey;
pBPK = BIO_new_mem_buf ( ( void* ) strKey.data(), -1 );
pPrivKey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey ( pBPK, NULL, NULL, NULL );
BIO_free ( pBPK );
unsigned char* from = ( unsigned char* ) strData.data();
unsigned char* to = new unsigned char[ RSA_size ( pPrivKey )];
int res=RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size ( pPrivKey ), from,to, pPrivKey, 1 );
```

And my openssl.net code is:

```
string publicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDOx0DsbBURESmUVivbiHXqJdaJ
w8j3v27RC5ArUKIFbzgoqge+ZA9IcWA+WDjW4auzrzhK3sQTHRbkYCkSZsHdkHFu
1viYDtK0Y1PUzm45xGAjOD2RTbYTMDyUAwDwERoIamPFLa/kQ/4AQnL6F2C6NQPt
nkCITLsB0+pbQLvLzwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
Encoding enc = Encoding.ASCII;
string text = "1234";
byte[] msg = enc.GetBytes(text);
CryptoKey key = CryptoKey.FromPublicKey(publicKey, "");
RSA rsa = key.GetRSA();
byte[] res = rsa.PublicEncrypt(msg, RSA.Padding.PKCS1);
rsa.Dispose();
strRes = Convert.ToBase64String(res);
```

Base64 encrypted data:

```
xJTlJeLlm3mufFAdUWFUPfF8KmzFEpIL5K2ibFnnmq4zNECW1conDsWytwGCrqPKOlbmIuhBlg2cUqw6FC6ntyOBSwgRiUht1mBKK+91e7M0h0jb7UTxEmpue+3sVCgjIW6I9GJDo5EA9q5xZA7xzlBh8DGJqOatpLbOt+jJDOw=
```

Original data: 1234

RSA_private_decrypt() returns -1.

Comment: Small nit: `const char *p="...";` should probably be changed to `static const char p[]="...";`.

Answer (score 0):

Your public key isn't correct which is a reason why decrypting later is not working (your openssl.net code should fail on loading it). Encrypting and decrypting using private key is working fine.